# Metropolis-Hastings Algorithm for Numerical Integration

Tags: markov-process, metropolis-hastings, numerical-integration

I'm attempting to implement a Metropolis-Hastings Algorithm to evaluate integrals of the following form:

$$I =\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {f(x)\exp(-x^2)} \text{d}x$$

Now we can rewrite this as:

$$I =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {f(x)P(x)} \text{d}x$$

Where:

$$ P(x) =  \mathcal{N}(\mu=0,\,\sigma^{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}) $$

Now I believe we should generate $X^*$ from some density $q(X^*|X_n)$

Generally we use $q(X^*|X_n) \sim \mathcal{N}(X_n,\,\sigma^{2}) $

We accept $X^* \ as\  X_{n+1}$ with probability:

$ \alpha(X^*, X_n)= min(1, \frac{P(X^*)}{P(X)})$

Else  $X_{n+1} = X_n$

So that's how we sample values.

Will the integral then tend towards:

$I \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum f(X_i)$

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I don't understand why one would want anything besides a uniform distribution .  The M-H algo presumes that there is a prior distribution on the probabilities of going from one state to another.  But 'dx' means, if you will, sample at random.

Comment: I think we sample from the normal distribution because it is symmetric. If you look at the tag description for metropolis-hastings it tells us: $$\alpha=\min\left(1,\frac{\mathscr{p}(x^\star)\mathscr{q}(x_t|x^\star)}{\mathscr{p}(x_t)\mathscr{q}(x^*|x_t)}\right)$$ This however simplifies if q is symmetric

Comment: @John Meighan is this something as a toy example or to study  M-H algorithm? Generally you use MH and more generally Monte Carlo integration when you cannot write down the integral in closed form or you are in a high dimensional space. A standard 1-d quadrature rule should work perfectly fine to evaluate this integral for any specified $f(x)$.

Comment: @LucasRoberts Yea I just want to study M-H algorithm.

Comment: In going from the first expression for $I$ to the second expression, I believe the factor $1/\sqrt{\pi}$ gets absorbed into $P(x)$.

Comment: @mef You're right I edited that out.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your conjecture is correct.

However, in this case there is a better proposal distribution. As you note the the comments, the acceptance probability is given by
\begin{equation}
\alpha = \min\left(1, \frac{p(x^*)\,q(x_t|x^*)}{p(x_t)\,q(x^*|x_t)}\right) . 
\end{equation}
Let $q(x^*|x_t) =\mathcal{N}(x^*|0,1/2)$. Then $p(x^*) = q(x^*|x_t)$ and $p(x_t) = q(x_t|x^*)$ and consequently $\alpha \equiv 1$. In other words you always accept with this proposal.

Comment: This is, of course, more efficient...but also kinda cheating because it takes advantage of the fact that we can already draw directly from the target distribution. If that's the case, MH sampling is in no way necessary. So in real applications, we will never have that $p = q$ (or we shouldn't be using MH)

Comment: In real world applications you may have a Gibbs sampler, which can be expressed as a Metropolis-Hastings sampler where, because of the cancellation involved, produces $\alpha \equiv 1$.